# Categories not shown in admin after adding woocommerce products via wp wc cli

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, wp-cli

After the following script is run

```
wp wc product create --name='b' --categories=32 --user=user
```

Output is printed:

```
Success: Created product 1370.
```

But no categories are shown in wp-admin/WooCommerce->Products page for the newly added product.

I have followed [Find Product Category IDs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/find-product-category-ids/) to get category id.
Tried to use [32], ['32'] instead of 32. The result is the same. Category is not shown in wordpress admin.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening [issue on woocommerce github page](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15220) and authorss reaction.

The solution is

```
wp wc product create --name='Product Name' --categories='[ { "id" : 21 } ]' --user=admin
```